# How can we create a common node modules folder which can be shared among mutliple angular7 apps

Tags: angular, angular7, node-modules

I have created an Base application in angular7 which has node modules.
I am looking for a way where multiple ng7 apps can refer node modules from Base application.

Have tried adding paths in "tsconfig.json", but it doesn't help since according to node resolution it tries to resolve within application root folder and if it cannot find then only it tries to find at a higher level folder.
when i delete root level node module ,so that it can refer Base applications node module , im getting @angular/devkit error